# Why can't I change backdrop to 'true' or remove it after changing to 'static' in Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to figure out why I can't change the backdrop to 'true' after first changing it to 'static' when using Bootstrap's modal.

I run this code:

```
$('#modal').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false, show: true});

$.post('server.php', $('#form').serialize(), function(data) {
    if(data.success) {
        $('#modal').modal({backdrop: true, keyboard: true});
    } else {
        $('#modal').modal({backdrop: true, keyboard: true});
    }
}, 'json');
```

It will set it so the backdrop and keyboard will not function at the start, but I cannot figure out why I can't set it back to default.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/1ua34q60/)

it looks like twitter bootstrap is storing all data in a data variable called `bs.modal`. so just remove that data variable and reinitialize the modal.

Your final code will look something like this

```
$('#modal').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false, show: true});

$.post('server.php', $('#form').serialize(), function(data) {
    if(data.success) {
        $('#modal').removeData('bs.modal').modal({backdrop: true, keyboard: true});
    } else {
        $('#modal').removeData('bs.modal').modal({backdrop: true, keyboard: true});
    }
}, 'json');
```

Answer (score 3):

The above solution was not working fine for me.

So I destroyed this instance of modal using this :-

```
$('#modal-xl').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
     $("#modal-xl").modal('dispose'); 
})
```

[Check working of dispose method here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#modaldispose)

Answer (score 1):

Follow up to the solution presented by [@Cerlin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003182/cerlin): I could not simply remove all data set to [Bootstrap v4.6](https://getbootstrap.com/)'s [modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/modal/), since I had other functionality attached to it. Using [jQuery v3.6](https://jquery.com/)'s [$.extend()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/), I was able to modify the data directly to allow the backdrop/keyboard to be usable again. If you don't use jQuery and do not support [Internet Explorer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#browser_compatibility), you could always use JavaScript's built-in method [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

```
// Variable Defaults
var bootstrapModal = $('.modal');
var bootstrapData  = bootstrapModal.data('bs.modal');

// Release Modal Backdrop
bootstrapModal.data('bs.modal', $.extend(true, bootstrapData, {
    _config: $.extend(true, bootstrapData._config, {
        backdrop: true,
        keyboard: true
    })
}));
```